# Why does cin.clear() fix an infinite loop caused by bad input to cin?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, cin

I've written a switch statement, and created a default which would simply say the user picked a bad option and repeat the input. I wanted to make sure that if there was an issue, it would clear the buffer first, so I used cin.sync(), but entering an 'a' for the input still caused an infinite loop. I added cin.clear() to clear the flags which gave me working code ... but my confusion is why it worked. Does cin.sync() not work if there is a fail flag?

the statement follows, truncated for brevity:

```
while(exitAllow == false)
{
    cout<<"Your options are:\n";
    cout<<"1: Display Inventory\n";
    /*truncated*/
    cout<<"5: Exit\n";
    cout<<"What would you like to do? ";

    cin.clear();   //HERE IS MY CONFUSION//
    cin.sync();
    cin>>action;
    switch(action)
    {
        case 1:
                    /*truncated*/
        case 5:
            exitAllow = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"\ninvalid entry!\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you try to read and it fails, the stream is marked to be in a *fail* state, and all subsequent attempts to read will fail automatically until you clear the fail flag, which is done with the `clear()` function.

You should check the status of the stream *after* each read:

```
if (cin >> var) {
   // do something sensible
} else {
   cin.clear();
}
```

Otherwise the value stored in `var` after the last successful read will be considered to be the current input for your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you sir. Also, "do something sensible" made me laugh.